# How to handle expired ManagedIdentity token in case of webjobs scheduled to run once every 24 hours of time?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-webjobs, azure-managed-identity

I have a webjob hosted in Azure which is scheduled to run once every 24 hours of time. For all the database operations within the webjob, I am using EntitytFrameworkCore and leveraging the token generated by using the ManagedIdentity. The token lifetime in this case is 24 hours. For the first time the webjob runs successfully without any issues, but on the next iterations post 24 hours it breaks , since the token by that time has expired.

I wanted to refresh the token in this case and perform the database operations.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to refresh the token in this case and perform the database operations

- As per this  document  - [How to use managed identities for App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal,http#configure-target-resource)

> There's currently no way to force a token refresh.

- The service provider sets the cache duration of the token generated by a Managed Identity endpoint, and it appears that there is no way to force a refresh.
- As per this document - [Are managed identities tokens cached?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-faq#are-managed-identities-tokens-cached)

> it is not possible to force a managed identity's token to be refreshed before its expiry